# Combine latest records with table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am using mysql and I am having the following two tables:

**Products**:

```
| id | name      |
|----|-----------|
| 1  | Product 1 |
| 2  | Product 2 |
| 3  | Product 3 |
```

**Prices**:

```
| id | Product_id | created_at          | prices |
|----|------------|---------------------|--------|
| 1  | 1          | 2017-12-23 08:32:11 | 10     |
| 2  | 1          | 2017-11-21 03:33:10 | 12     |
| 3  | 2          | 2017-12-23 08:32:11 | 43     |
| 4  | 2          | 2017-11-21 03:33:10 | 23     |
| 5  | 3          | 2017-12-23 08:32:11 | 78     |
| 6  | 3          | 2017-11-21 03:33:10 | 34     |
```

If I do:

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE prices.id IN ( SELECT MAX(prices.id) FROM prices GROUP BY prices.created_at )
```

This gives me the last prices for each product_id:

```
| id | Product_id | created_at          | prices |
|----|------------|---------------------|--------|
| 1  | 1          | 2017-12-23 08:32:11 | 10     |
| 3  | 2          | 2017-12-23 08:32:11 | 43     |
| 5  | 3          | 2017-12-23 08:32:11 | 78     |
```

I would like to have as **final result** all Products with the latest prices, which would look like the following:

```
| id | name      | product_id | created_at          | prices |
|----|-----------|------------|---------------------|--------|
| 1  | Product 1 | 1          | 2017-12-23 08:32:11 | 10     |
| 2  | Product 2 | 2          | 2017-12-23 08:32:11 | 43     |
| 3  | Product 3 | 3          | 2017-12-23 08:32:11 | 78     |
```

However, I am not sure how to combine:

```
select * from products
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM prices WHERE prices.id IN ( SELECT MAX(prices.id) FROM prices GROUP BY prices.created_at )
```

I highly appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your first query is giving you expected result, just use `join`.

```
SELECT p.*,d.name FROM prices p
inner join product d 
on d.id=p.product_id
WHERE 
p.id IN 
    ( SELECT MAX(prices.id) FROM prices GROUP BY prices.created_at )
```

If you believe that there are product id in `price` which are not mapped in `product` then use `left join` instead of `inner join`.

Comment: Thx for your reply! I face one problem with your query. If a price is not updated on the same `created_date` - as shown above with `2017-12-23 08:32:11` - then it is left out. So if a Price has for example the `created_date` on `2017-04-23 05:55:55` then it is left out with the above query.

Comment: could be corrected gouping by mean of `prices.product_id`. But this way of getting the most recent created price (`MAX()` of `prices.price_id` autoincrement) is weird having `prices.created_at` available

Answer (score 0):

I think  you have get max total  price with product name  so below is query according your given tables

select prices.id, products.id,products.product, sum(prices.prices) as Totalprices from prices join products on prices.id=products.id group by prices.id order by Totalprices desc limit 1

Hope it help you

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the latest prices are the most recent created ones and depicted by `prices.created_at` value, to get the latest prices you could better rely on `prices.created_at`, instead of assuming chronological ordering by mean of `prices.id` (autoincrement), as in:

```
SELECT products.id, products.name, prices.created_at, prices.prices
FROM products 
INNER JOIN prices ON products.id=prices.product_id
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT product_id, MAX(created_at) AS created_at FROM prices GROUP BY product_id) AS LATEST_PRICES
on prices.product_id=LATEST_PRICES.product_id
-- WHERE prices.created_at = LATEST_PRICES.created_at
AND prices.created_at = LATEST_PRICES.created_at
```